# ruby on rails rspec command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

So as a beginner I am following Michael Hart's ruby on rails 2nd edition tutorial !

when I run command line with the integration test module

```
rspec test/integration/static_pages_test.rb
```

it's not showing what Hartl's getting. Instead it's showing this :

```
/Users/Name/rails_testprojects/protego/test/integration/static_pages_test.rb:1:in `require': no such file to load -- test_helper (LoadError)
    from /Users/Name/rails_testprojects/protego/test/integration/static_pages_test.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@twitclone/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `load'
    from /Users/Name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@twitclone/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /Users/Name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@twitclone/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `map'
    from /Users/Name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@twitclone/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `load_spec_files'
    from /Users/Name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@twitclone/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
    from /Users/Name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@twitclone/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in `run'
    from /Users/Name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@twitclone/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:8:in `block in autorun'
```

Note : In Hartl's tutorial , the integration test is in a different folder called !

```
bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb
```

can someone please explain what's going on ? I am a total beginner and have just started following his tutorials !

Comment: require 'test_helper' this is written somewhere in your file??? thats why it throws error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say you're following [Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial book](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/book/ruby-on-rails-tutorial), but you really aren't following it; at least not as rigorously as required ;-)

Rails Tutorial book uses [RSpec](http://rspec.info) as the testing framework of choice. In rspec, all the test files are under `spec` folder, and are called `specs`.

[Rails by default](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#brief-note-about-test-unit) comes with [Test::Unit](https://github.com/test-unit/test-unit) testing framework, and it places the files under `test` folder.

You are mixing both of them and are getting confused.

I suggest you to stick with what's there in Rails Tutorial book, and rigorously follow the instructions there to get the most out of your time spent in learning rails.